# OpenCV captures only a fraction of the frames from a video file

Tags: opencv

I'm using OpenCV to do some processing on an AVI file. Everything is working fine, except for the fact that only a small fraction of the frames in the original video are being captured.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
capture=cvCaptureFromAVI(PATH_TO_VIDEO);
int fps=(int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
int frames=(int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
qDebug("%d frames at %d fps",frames,fps);
int framesSaved=0;

while(1) {
    frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if(!frame) break;

    framesSaved++;
    data = (uchar *)frame->imageData;
    //PROCESSING
    cvWriteFrame(writer,frame);
}

cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
qDebug("VIDEO SAVED: %d frames",framesSaved);
```

The output:

```
1948 frames at 50 fps
VIDEO SAVED: 105 frames
```

Any idea what the problem could be?

Thanks

Comment: It could also be a different error while decoding next frame. `NULL` from cvQueryFrame needs not mean EOF. Maybe the file is damaged / incomplete.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OpenCV VideoCapture is known to have serious problems to report correct number of frames with `CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`

The good news is that the guys at OpenCV are working hard to fix it for the next release.

Comment: The frame count is correct in this case. The video input video is ~20s long.

Comment: The chance for OpenCV to read less frames is very, very low. The chance to read a wrong number is very high. You can test it with other video capture backend - Windows Media or Quick time, to see whether the number of frames is different.

Comment: This "OpenCV Meeting notes" link is getting a 404 error

Comment: This is still not fixed as of OpenCV 2.4.9.

Comment: How about OpenCV 3.0.0?

Comment: No problems with this property in OpenCV 3.4.1 (Python 3.6 bindings from conda-forge) - so far. Of course, for webcam it's `-1.0`, and for an HTTP stream e.g. `-9.223372036854776e+18` ;)