# How to find the length of a video in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to find the length of a video capture in OpenCV;

```
int frameNumbers = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(video2, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
int fps = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(video2, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
int videoLength = frameNumbers / fps;
```

but this give me a result which is less than the real answer. What do I have to do?

Comment: A lot of the cvGetCapture props don't work - they rely on the OS (vfw/directshow) supplying the right values. You might want to use ffmpeg directly if the results matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this similar post. OpenCV cannt (yet) capture correctly the number of frames

[OpenCV captures only a fraction of the frames from a video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547102/opencv-captures-only-a-fraction-of-the-frames-from-a-video-file/9549717#9549717)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I am not sure if there is any issue with the functions that you tried as of today. However, There is an issue with this snippet. Here, it is being assumed that Frames Per Second is an integer value which is not always the case. For example, many videos are encoded at 29.97 FPS, and this code would assume int(29.97) = 29 which obviously results in a larger value in seconds for video length.

The calculation seems to work fine for me if I use floating point values (float) without truncating them.