# Determine the length of capture video Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video

Below is the code I currently use for to calculate the video length, but the result show as:Length of video= 0; Frame Numbers of video = 271; FPS of video = -2147483648

The length of video is 0 while there are value for frame numbers of video and FPS of video. I include head library which is cmath.

```
CvCapture*capture=cvCaptureFromAVI("1.mp4");
int frameNumbers = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
int fps = (int) cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
int videoLength2 = frameNumbers/fps*(-1);
cout<<"Length of video      ="<<videoLength<<endl;
cout<<"Frame Numbers of video   ="<<frameNumbers<<endl;
cout<<"FPS of video ="<<fps<<endl;
```

Comment: I got the same you need, May be it could help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547102/opencv-captures-only-a-fraction-of-the-frames-from-a-video-file/9549717#9549717

Comment: I guess you need to update you opencv version and then try it, if the problem with cvGetCaptureProperty is got fixed. It is know as per my above comment

Comment: I afraid update opencv will make some of my previous code can not run. I now using opencv 2.4.9.

Comment: you can try and check , in my guess this should work.

Comment: So what you mean try will be update my opencv to 3.0?